# Javascript button event not working after page 1

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, razor

Essentially I have some datatable like this: Now for some reason when I go to the second page, none of the buttons I have are working. Like when I click them nothing happens! But on the first page they work perfectly! Not sure how to fix this issue! [enter image description here][1]

```
//creation method of the table

var volunteerTable = $('#volunteerTable').DataTable({
     paging: true,
     pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
     columns: [ title:"First Name", title:"Last Name", title:"Email"



The trash can button code:
$('.buttonVDelete').click(function () {
    
//fill out the fields
//open the delete volunteer modal
//prepare data to send

}
```

Comment: seriously? no one can possibly help you with what you have shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `click()` you are reading the elements available at the moment of loading the page.

In order to read new rendered elements, you must use [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','.buttonVDelete', function () {
  // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

is it jQuery required? maybe better vanilla javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.buttonVDelete').addEventListener('click', 
  function(){

  })
```

Most of modern browser can easy deal with es5/es6

I hope I helped.